# how to transfer files from AWS S3 to Raspberry pi?

Tags: amazon-s3, raspberry-pi, aws-lambda

I have a set of files in S3. I need to transfer updated files in S3 bucket to raspberry pi using Lambda trigger function. Can anyone guide me

Answer (score 0):

I would follow this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdk-setup.html then take a look at this advanced example https://spindance.com/pattern-secure-uploads-downloads-aws-iot/